# Why does my Tizen Web App behave differently in debug mode?

Tags: debugging, tizen, tizen-web-app

In debug mode

```
tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().getRequestedAppControl()
```

works like a charm. But in run mode my app chrashes at this line.

Comment: Have you tried to call them seperatly in order to get the function call that causes the error?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for a launch request, use a try-catch block like following:

```
function checkLaunchRequest() {
        var appControl
        ,   appOperation
        ,   tmp
        ;

        try {
            appControl = app.getCurrentApplication().getRequestedAppControl().appControl;
            appOperation = appControl.operation;
            console.log("checkLaunchRequest operation: " + appOperation);

            if (appOperation.indexOf("http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/view") !== -1) {
                ...Do something here...
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Invalid launch request: " + err.message);
        }
    }
```

Also be sure you have set correct privilege in config.xml. You will need to set "http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch".